# (c) expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c, if-statement, lvalue

```
if (operation = '+' || operation = '-' || operation = '*' || operation = '/' || operation = '%')//error line
    {
        printf("Enter the first operand:\t\t");
        getchar();
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        printf("Enter the second operand:\t\t");
        getchar();
        scanf("%d", &num2);
}
```

It gives out an error saying :

```
Error: expresion must be a modifiable value
```

It gives me the error on that if line , on all of the arguments but the one that says

```
operation = '%'
```

what is the problem ??
thank you guys :)

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` comparison.

Comment: You must mean `==` in `if` statement ?

Comment: (Unrelated) Should you not store the result of your `getchar()` somewhere?

Comment: @Jongware ,I think they are placed to eat the `\n` left out by `scanf`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a typo and instead of the comparison operator `==` you wrote the assignment operator `=`

Instead of

```
if (operation = '+' || operation = '-' || operation = '*' || operation = '/' || operation = '%')
```

there must be

```
if (operation == '+' || operation == '-' || operation == '*' || operation == '/' || operation == '%')
```

You could write the if statement simpler. For example

```
const char *Operations = "+-*/%";

char *p = strchr( Operations, operation );

if ( p !=  NULL )
{
        printf("Enter the first operand:\t\t");
        getchar();
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        printf("Enter the second operand:\t\t");
        getchar();
        scanf("%d", &num2);
}
```

Or even without declaring pointer `p`

```
const char *Operations = "+-*/%";

if ( strchr( Operations, operation ) !=  NULL )
{
        printf("Enter the first operand:\t\t");
        getchar();
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        printf("Enter the second operand:\t\t");
        getchar();
        scanf("%d", &num2);
}
```

Comment: I think for someone who doesn't yet know the difference between `==` and `=` this may be a little complex.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double equal (`==`) signs, rather than single equals (`=`):

```
if (operation == '+' || operation == '-' || operation == '*' //...
```

the equals (`=`) is reserved just for assignment, so won't work when you are trying to compare values.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, you must use the equal operator (==) and not the assignment operator (=). What's happening is the following: The compiler tries to make an assignment that looks like

```
var = (x || y) = var
```

So it tries to assign the value of var to a boolean expression (namely `(x || y)`), and this irritates the compiler. This is why it works on the last assignment (%), because then the compiler knows what to do: assign '%' to operation. Still this won't work as you intended, but at least it compiles. You actually **can** put an assignment in an if statement. What happens is that the value of the assigned variable (i.e. operation) will be evaluated, and the statement is true if the value is != 0, false otherwise.

Comment: you can assign the output of a logical operator: var = 1==1 will set var equal to true.

Comment: you are right, i corrected my answer. i think that i now have described the actual cause of the compiler error.

Comment: `var = x || y` groups as `var = (x || y)`.

Comment: right, and then it goes on: var = (x || y) = var... which means he's trying to assing var to (x || y)