# C Expression must be a modifiable value

Tags: c

```
while (from[i] != '\0')
{
    while (from[i] != '\t' && from[i] != ' '&& from[i] = '\n')
    {
        to[j] = from[i];
        ++i;
        ++j;
    }....
```

Hello, newbie here learning C.
I get "Expression must be a modifiable value" error on the 3rd line above.
Exactly from 'from[i] != '\t'
But I am not trying to modify any value here as far as I know.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is from in this instance? is it an array? can you pls post the rest of the code :)

Comment: You have an accidental assignment later on in your second while loop: from[i] = '\n', change it to from[i] == '\n'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(c) expression must be a modifiable lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945802/c-expression-must-be-a-modifiable-lvalue)

Answer (score 0):

On line three `from[i] = '\n'` should be `from[i] == '\n'` (with two equals signs). This is because one equals sign means assignment while two equal signs means comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (from[i] != '\0')
{
    while (from[i] != '\t' && from[i] != ' '&& from[i] != '\n')//You had an accidental assignment here
    {
        to[j] = from[i];
        ++i;
        ++j;
    }....
```

I still dont see why you would get a compilation issue, it seems like you would always assign it and get a runtime issue, but i dont know what compiler/settings you're using.  Let me know if that fixes it.